# How to sort a D3 bar chart (based on an array of objects) by value or key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, d3.js, bar-chart

I am new to d3 and javascript in general and I'm trying to wrap my head around some possible interactions with rather simple bar charts.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I would like to have the option to sort my bar chart by value when you click on one of the bars and then alphabetically by keys if you click once more.

**My progress so far:**

My bar chart is based on an array of objects where the keys are names of companies and the values indicate the mean satisfaction with each company on a scale from 0 to 100.

```
var data = [
    {key: "Test 1",  value: 21},
    {key: "Test 2",  value: 34},
    ...
    {key: "Test 12", value: 22},
    {key: "Test 13", value: 97}
];
```

You can see my progress and the whole code here: [bl.ocks.org](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/e6235baef0c18968bb78ef64359fc07d/8bc8f60d661edc11f1c528031104bfecf0e4c9c0)

I attempted to create a function to sort the array. But then I'm pretty much lost on how to actually reposition the bars since all the bars are originally positioned based on their key and I don't know how else to do it on a ordinal scale.

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d){
        return d.key;
    }))
    .range([margin.left, width])
    .padding(0.1);

 var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
        return d.value;
    })])
    .range([height, margin.top])


 var sortBars = function(){
 svg.selectAll("rect")
    .sort(function(a,b){
        return b.value-a.value;      
    })
    .transition("sort")
    .duration(100)
    .attr("x", function(d,i){
        return x(d.key);
    })  
 }
```

At first I thought if I sort the array, then the return value based on the key should be based on the new order, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you very much in advance for any tips or help!

Comment: Demo https://shanegibney.github.io/D3-v4-Sortable-Bar-Chart-Radio-Button-Time-Value/

Comment: The code for sorting by key or by value https://github.com/shanegibney/D3-v4-Sortable-Bar-Chart-Radio-Button-Time-Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this is sorting the **data array**, and recalculating the domain. By key:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(a.key, b.key)
})
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.key;
}));
```

And by value:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.descending(a.value, b.value)
})
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.key;
}));
```

Here is your bl.ocks with those changes, I put two buttons: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/bc5a9691a3417b403d4e8ade3297afa3/3a2434c1c2849e476791e581754ec27e055db4d6

PS: Have in mind that sorting by key is sorting **strings**. Therefore, "Test 2" comes after "test 13". If you want the sequence "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3" etc, you'll have to modify your strings.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you very much! I tried sorting the array before, but I somehow did not think about recalculating the domain as well.